# Horizontal Naviation Bar with customized h1 text

Tags: html, css, frontend, css-position, navigationbar

All I want is to put the icon in the left and let it be horizontally aligned with the title.
Here is the CodePen: https://codepen.io/mrlima/pen/WNgoGew

I'm really new to front-end coding, I'm much better with Javascript Algorthims, please, be patient with me because English is my second language.

```
/*HTML*/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Poise Idiomas</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e424189c9b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="topnav">
      <h1 id="title">
        <i style="float:left;"class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
        <span class="green">P</span><span class="yellow">O</span><span class="blue">I</span><span class="yellow">S</span><span class="green">E</span>
        <span class="fancy-canada-flag">Idiomas</span><span class="fancy" style="font-size:30pt;">.com</span>
      </h1>
  </div>
  <script src="script/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
/*CSS*/
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster&family=Tilt+Warp&display=swap");
:root {
  --bg-color: rgba(20, 20, 20, 1);
}
html, body {
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  color: white;
  font-family: "Tilt Warp", cursive;
  margin:0px;
  padding:2px;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
::selection{
  background: transparent;
  color: #d12628;
}
.topnav{
  /* display:inline; */
}
#title {
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 6rem;
  color: #ef233c;
}
/* ------------------------------------------------------- */
.blue {color: #002776;}
.yellow {color: #ffdf00;}
.green {color: #009c3b;}
.white {color: #ffffff;}
.fancy{font-family: "Lobster";color:#d12628;}
.fancy-canada-flag {
  font-family: "Lobster";
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d9/Flag_of_Canada_(Pantone).svg/800px-Flag_of_Canada_(Pantone).svg.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
}

/*No Javascript code written.*/
```

Comment: it is not good way to add menu button to h1 tag!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that I want to mention is to not use float and use flex instead.
remove the float part in the  tag. add a div around the spans and add these to the CSS.

```
#title {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
text-align:center;
font-size: 6rem;
color: #ef233c;
}
.title_container{
flex-grow: 1;
}
```

and here is the HTML part

```
<h1 id="title">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
    <div class="title_container">
        <span class="green">P</span><span class="yellow">O</span><span 
class="blue">I</span><span class="yellow">S</span><span 
class="green">E</span>
        <span class="fancy-canada-flag">Idiomas</span><span class="fancy" 
style="font-size:30pt;">.com</span>
    </div>
  </h1>
```

look at [the pen](https://codepen.io/Niloofar_araz/pen/MWqbjbE) that I wrote for it.
:)